# How to sort JTable by column?

Tags: java, swing, jtable

How would I sort a `JTable` by the column "quantity" in descending order? I am adding the data in the table by scanning text file and adding each thing to an object, etc. if that makes sense.

What is the simplest way of doing this?

```
tblProduct = new JTable();
scrollPane.setViewportView(tblProduct);

dtmProduct = new DefaultTableModel();
dtmProduct.setColumnIdentifiers(new Object[] {"Barcode", "Device Name", "Device Type", "Brand", "Colour", "Connectivity", "Quantity", "Retail Price", "Add. Info."});
tblProduct.setModel(dtmProduct);

JButton btnViewProducts = new JButton("View all");
btnViewProducts.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        try {
            ArrayList<Product> productList = new ArrayList<Product>();
            File inputFile = new File("Stock.txt");
            Scanner fileScanner = new Scanner(inputFile);
            Product product;            
            
            while (fileScanner.hasNextLine()) {
                String[] details = fileScanner.nextLine().split(",") ;
                product = new Product(Integer.parseInt(details[0].trim()), details[1].trim(), details[2].trim(), details[3].trim(), details[4].trim(), details[5].trim(), Integer.parseInt(details[6].trim()), Float.parseFloat(details[7].trim()), Float.parseFloat(details[8].trim()), details[9].trim());
                productList.add(product); 
            } 
            
            for(Product product1: productList) {
                Object[] rowdata = new Object[] {product1.getbarcode(), product1.getdeviceName(), product1.getdeviceType(), product1.getbrand(), product1.getcolour(), product1.getconnectivity(), product1.getquantity(), product1.getretailPrice(), product1.getadditionalInformation()};
                dtmProduct.addRow(rowdata);
```

Comment: this url will help you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28823670/how-to-sort-jtable-in-shortest-way

Comment: Start by looking at [`JTable`, Sorting and Filtering](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#sorting), for [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28823670/how-to-sort-jtable-in-shortest-way/28823706#28823706)